# CXF: how to exclude some properties when object sent through SOAP?

Tags: java, cxf

I use Apache CXF 2.4.2 and when I'm returnimg some object from the database to user I want to exclude some properties (for instance, password). How I can do that **without creating temporary** class? Is there annotation for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per @tomasz-nurkiewicz comment I should use [`@XmlTransient`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html) annotation. But as noted in documentation

> By default, if @XmlAccessorType on a class is absent, and none of its super classes is annotated with @XmlAccessorType, then the following default on the class is assumed:
>
> @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)

Where `XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER` means that:

> Every public getter/setter pair and every public field will be automatically bound to XML, unless annotated by XmlTransient. Fields or getter/setter pairs that are private, protected, or defaulted to package-only access are bound to XML only when they are explicitly annotated by the appropriate JAXB annotations.

So this is why `@XmlTransient` for private field doesn't work in example from Tomasz Nurkiewicz. There are two possible ways to fix that:

1) Add annotation to public getter:

```
private String password;

@XmlTransient
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
```

2) Add `@XmlAccessorType` to class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public User {

    @XmlTransient
    private String password;

}
```

Found at: http://old.nabble.com/@XmlTransient-ignored-td7406659.html

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using JAXB for object-XML mapping. In that case simply annotate fields you want to skip in your database entity with `@XmlTransient`.

```
@XmlTransient
private String password;
```

However note that one day you will realize that you **do need** a temporary class mainly to decouple your CXF web service from the backend. After all you don't want to remember all the time that adding a column in the database immediately breaks the SOAP interface...

Comment: I'm not sure what I use, because I've only added `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws` and `cxf-rt-transports-http` to my `pom.xml` for using CXF. But I see `jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar` and `cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.4.3.jar` in my WAR package, so looks like you are right. I tried to use `@XmlTransient` without luck :( I also added `@XmlRootElement` to whole class, but nothing changed. Did you have another tip?

Comment: Hi again! I googling and do little research and found how to resolve my problem. See my update. Also I upvote your answer because it helps me to find right solution. Thank you!