# WebService - could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: spring, apache, hibernate, web-services, cxf

I try to get a List of Data from my database by WebService. I use Spring and Hibernate
I have read some topic like
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592583/error-during-invoking-webservice-could-not-initialize-proxy-no-session) or [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439306/org-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-could-not-initialize-proxy-no-sessi)

So I try o put some Transactionnal on the top of class, on my method, etc, but not working, or I did'nt put the right thing at the right place with right parameter.

Thank you, sorry if grammar bad

**EDIT**:
I think the problem come from my class Personne which got link with lot of other entitys in lazy mode, is it a mean to say at the web service, I don't care of this link when I return the object ? Or to say to fetch all

Here is my service, the interface only have the @WebService annotation

```
    @WebService(endpointInterface = "eu.enslyon.stella.service.CasMessageService")
    @Service("CasMessageService")
    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public class CasMessageServiceImpl implements CasMessageService {
        private transient Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("CasMessageDao")
        protected CasMessageDao casMessageDao;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("IndividuUlrService")
        protected IndividuUlrService individuUlrService;


        @Override
        @Transactional(readOnly = true)
        public List get(String pLogin) {
            BigDecimal persId = individuUlrService.getPersIdFromLogin(pLogin);

            return casMessageDao.get(persId);
        }

    }
```

My DAO, the interface don't have any annotation:

```
    @Repository("CasMessageDao")
    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public class CasMessageDaoImpl extends AbstractJpaDao implements CasMessageDao, java.io.Serializable {

        /**

         */
        private final static List> dataTypes = new ArrayList>(
                Arrays.asList(new Class[] { IndividuUlr.class }));

        /**

         */
        private static transient Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CasMessageDaoImpl.class);

        /**

         */
        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "grhum")
        private EntityManager entityManager;

        /**

         */
        public CasMessageDaoImpl() {
            super();
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @return List>
         */

        public List> getDataTypes() {
            return dataTypes;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @return EntityManager
         */
        public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
            return entityManager;
        }



        @Override
        public List get(BigDecimal persId) {

            CriteriaBuilder cBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = cBuilder.createQuery(CasMessage.class);

            Root lRoot = criteriaQuery.from(CasMessage.class);

            Join lJoinTypeMessage = lRoot.join("typeCasMessage", JoinType.LEFT);
            Join lJoinPersonne = lRoot.join("detailPersonne", JoinType.LEFT).join("personne",
                    JoinType.LEFT);

            lRoot.fetch("typeCasMessage");
            lRoot.fetch("detailPersonne").fetch("personne");

            criteriaQuery.where(cBuilder.and(cBuilder.isNull(lRoot. get("dEnd")),
                    cBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(lRoot. get("countignore"),
                            lJoinTypeMessage. get("nbAffichage")),
                    cBuilder.equal(lJoinPersonne. get("persId"), persId)));

            Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

            List lRes = query.getResultList();

            return lRes;
        }

    }
```

My entities:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "CAS_MESSAGE", schema = "STELLA")
    public class CasMessage implements java.io.Serializable {

        private int idCasMessage;
        private TypeCasMessage typeCasMessage;
        private Date dStart;
        private Date dUpdate;
        private Date dEnd;
        private int countignore;
        private DetailPersonne detailPersonne;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "CasMessage [idCasMessage=" + idCasMessage + ", dStart=" + dStart + ", dUpdate=" + dUpdate + ", dEnd="
                    + dEnd + ", countignore=" + countignore + ", detailPersonne=" + detailPersonne + "]";
        }

        public CasMessage() {
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CAS_MESSAGE_SEQ")
        @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "STELLA.CAS_MESSAGE_SEQ", name = "CAS_MESSAGE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
        @Column(name = "ID_CAS_MESSAGE", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 8, scale = 0)
        public int getIdCasMessage() {
            return idCasMessage;
        }

        public void setIdCasMessage(int idCasMessage) {
            this.idCasMessage = idCasMessage;
        }

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_TYPE_CAS_MESSAGE")
        public TypeCasMessage getTypeCasMessage() {
            return typeCasMessage;
        }

        public void setTypeCasMessage(TypeCasMessage typeCasMessage) {
            this.typeCasMessage = typeCasMessage;
        }

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "D_START", length = 7)
        public Date getdStart() {
            return dStart;
        }

        public void setdStart(Date dStart) {
            this.dStart = dStart;
        }

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "D_UPDATE", length = 7)
        public Date getdUpdate() {
            return dUpdate;
        }

        public void setdUpdate(Date dUpdate) {
            this.dUpdate = dUpdate;
        }

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "D_END", length = 7)
        public Date getdEnd() {
            return dEnd;
        }

        public void setdEnd(Date dEnd) {
            this.dEnd = dEnd;
        }

        @Column(name = "COUNTIGNORE", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 8, scale = 0)
        public int getCountignore() {
            return countignore;
        }

        public void setCountignore(int countignore) {
            this.countignore = countignore;
        }

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "PERS_ID")
        public DetailPersonne getDetailPersonne() {
            return this.detailPersonne;
        }

        public void setDetailPersonne(DetailPersonne detailPersonne) {
            this.detailPersonne = detailPersonne;
        }

    }
```

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TYPE_CAS_MESSAGE", schema = "STELLA")
    public class TypeCasMessage implements java.io.Serializable {

        private int idTypeCasMessage;
        private String message;
        private String url;
        private int nbJour;
        private int nbAffichage;

        public TypeCasMessage() {
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "TypeCasMessage [idTypeCasMessage=" + idTypeCasMessage + ", message=" + message + ", url=" + url
                    + ", nbJour=" + nbJour + ", nbAffichage=" + nbAffichage + "]";
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TYPE_CAS_MESSAGE_SEQ")
        @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "STELLA.TYPE_CAS_MESSAGE_SEQ", name = "TYPE_CAS_MESSAGE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
        @Column(name = "ID_TYPE_CAS_MESSAGE", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 8, scale = 0)
        public int getIdTypeCasMessage() {
            return idTypeCasMessage;
        }

        public void setIdTypeCasMessage(int idTypeCasMessage) {
            this.idTypeCasMessage = idTypeCasMessage;
        }

        @Column(name = "MESSAGE")
        @Lob
        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        @Column(name = "URL", length = 500)
        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        @Column(name = "NB_JOUR", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 8, scale = 0)
        public int getNbJour() {
            return nbJour;
        }

        public void setNbJour(int nbJour) {
            this.nbJour = nbJour;
        }

        @Column(name = "NB_AFFICHAGE", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 8, scale = 0)
        public int getNbAffichage() {
            return nbAffichage;
        }

        public void setNbAffichage(int nbAffichage) {
            this.nbAffichage = nbAffichage;
        }

    }
```

TRACE:

```
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: could not initialize proxy - no Session
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:249)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:169)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:111)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:78)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:110)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:98)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:423)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:178)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:142)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:103)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)





    Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:165)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
        at eu.enslyon.stella.model.CarteCumul_$$_jvst22d_7.getDDebResto(CarteCumul_$$_jvst22d_7.java)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$GetterSetterReflection.get(Accessor.java:347)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor.getUnadapted(Accessor.java:149)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.hasValue(TransducedAccessor.java:247)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:98)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:152)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:152)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:65)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:168)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:155)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:152)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:189)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:316)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:323)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:72)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:315)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:244)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.writeObject(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:532)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:222)
        ... 64 more
```

```
Conf for Entity Manager
<pre>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">


<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:config.properties" />
</bean>

<!-- Atomikos Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="forceShutdown" value="true" />
    <property name="startupTransactionService" value="true" />
    <property name="transactionTimeout" value="3600" />
</bean>

<bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp" />

<!-- JTA transactions from Atomikos -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager" />
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction" />
    <property name="transactionSynchronizationName" value="SYNCHRONIZATION_ON_ACTUAL_TRANSACTION" />

</bean>
<!-- Atomikos Data Sources -->
<bean name="grhumDS" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.nonxa.AtomikosNonXADataSourceBean">
    <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="[VALUE]" />
    <property name="url" value="${grhum.connection.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${grhum.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${grhum.connection.password}" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${grhum.connection.driver_class}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="150" />
    <property name="borrowConnectionTimeout" value="30" />

</bean>
<bean name="protecDS" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.nonxa.AtomikosNonXADataSourceBean">
    <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="[VALUE]" />
    <property name="url" value="${protec.connection.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${protec.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${protec.connection.password}" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${protec.connection.driver_class}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="150" />
    <property name="borrowConnectionTimeout" value="30" />
</bean>

<bean name="sesameDS" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.nonxa.AtomikosNonXADataSourceBean">
    <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="[VALUE]" />
    <property name="url" value="${sesame.connection.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${sesame.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${sesame.connection.password}" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${sesame.connection.driver_class}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="150" />
    <property name="borrowConnectionTimeout" value="30" />
</bean>


<!-- vendor adapter -->
<bean id="grhumJPAVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="${grhum.show_sql}" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="${grhum.generateDdl}" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="${grhum.dialect}" />
</bean>
<bean id="protecJPAVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="${protec.show_sql}" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="${protec.generateDdl}" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="${protec.dialect}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sesameJPAVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="${sesame.show_sql}" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="${sesame.generateDdl}" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="${sesame.dialect}" />
</bean>

<bean id="grhum"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="grhumDS" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="grhum" />

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="grhumJPAVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="on_close" />
            <entry key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="${catalina.base}/tmp/indexes" />
            <entry key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                value="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate4.AtomikosPlatform" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="eu.enslyon.stella.model" />

</bean>

<bean id="protec"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="protecDS" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="protec" />

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="protecJPAVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="on_close" />
            <entry key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="${catalina.base}/tmp/indexes" />
            <entry key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                value="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate4.AtomikosPlatform" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="eu.enslyon.stella.model.protec" />

</bean>


<bean id="sesame"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="sesameDS" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="sesame" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="sesameJPAVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="on_close" />
            <entry key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="${catalina.base}/tmp/indexes" />
            <entry key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                value="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate4.AtomikosPlatform" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Can we see the configuration file, how you create EM, btw why are using nested transaction? is there any specific use case

Comment: I have add it, I think it's that. 
For the "@Transactional(readOnly = true)", it's just a remaining of one of my test, sorry.
For the other, I just c/c the code of my boss in other case. I am an intern since 2month and learn this technologie during this period, so I am very noob on lot of points :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solve that by put "@XmlTransient" on :

```
     @XmlTransient
     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
            @JoinColumn(name = "PERS_ID")
            public DetailPersonne getDetailPersonne() {
                return this.detailPersonne;
            }
```

See [CXF: how to exclude some properties when object sent through SOAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711978/cxf-how-to-exclude-some-properties-when-object-sent-through-soap)

I didn't understood it was CXF which serialize my object and no hibernate so I searched with bad term and found nothing

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error. The problem was that object of soap response has link to persisted/attached collection. And during marshalling it causes the lazy loading exception. We fix this issue in the converter, just create copy of collection. For example:
**Old code with bug**:

```
soapResponseDto.setBookTypes(entity.getBookTypes);
```

**New fixed code**:

```
soapReponseDto.setBookType(new ArrayList<>(entity.getBookTypes));
```

So you need to check that soap reponse DTO classes do no contain any classes from entities.